# Cannot download correct version of Windows Media Feature Pack (iCloud/ Outlook syncing issue)

Tags: windows-10, sync, windows-update, microsoft-outlook-2013, icloud

I'm having a problem syncing my iCloud with my Outlook mailbox. My calendar, contacts and tasks have disappeared. I understand this is probably the result of some sort of compatibility issue with Windows 10.  I've had the problem before but managed to fix it previously but I'm having trouble doing so this time.

In order to fix it, I believe I need to upgrade my iCloud but to do that, I'm told I need to first update my Media Features Pack for Windows.  I am using Windows 10 Pro N (x64) and I have the Media Features Pack KB3010081 currently installed.  I've downloaded what I believe is the latest Media Features Pack KB3099229_x64 but when I try to install it, I get the message "Feature Pack for Windows KB3010081 is already installed on this computer".

It seems my system doesn't recognise that the latest update is different. I tried to uninstall the old version (KB3010081) in order to then re-install the new one, but the old one doesn't appear in the list of installed updates on my control panel (see pic).

I am at a loss and have been going round and round in circles. Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Feature Media Pack for Windows 10 at the following locations.

1. [Media Feature Pack for N versions of Windows 10 - Version 1607](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53356)
2. [Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 10 - July 2015 RTM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231)
3. [Media Feature Pack for Windows 10 N and Windows 10 KN editions (November 2015) - Version 1511](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3099229)

You want the want for the current version, Version 1607, any other version is not appliciable to your installation of Windows 10.

- [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3145500/media-feature-pack-list-for-windows-n-editions) page has a list of the media packs released for each of the feature updates released before January 2018.
- [This](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack) page has a list of the media packs released for each of the feature updates released after January 2018.