# Android 7.0 Galaxy S6 edge+ can't connect to win10 computer via USB

Tags: windows-10, usb, android, windows-media-player, mtp

I have a similar problem as [Windows 10 is unable to load Android devices as MTP devices after installing Media feature pack](https://superuser.com/questions/1160387/windows-10-is-unable-to-load-android-devices-as-mtp-devices-after-installing-med?rq=1).

Windows 10 Pro N
Version 1703
Build 15063.540

Tried installing: KB3010081, KB3099229 and 3133719.

It still will not recognize my Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+ running Android 7.0

Screenshot of [winver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU7Rs.png)

Screenshot of [installed updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEf91.png)

Comment: Related: [Cannot download correct version of Windows Media Feature Pack (iCloud/ Outlook syncing issue)](https://superuser.com/questions/1141980/cannot-download-correct-version-of-windows-media-feature-pack-icloud-outlook-s/1142024#1142024)

Comment: Find more android USB driver @ http://adbshell.com/downloads

Comment: How about to use Linux bash to access your smartphone-data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I Tried installing: KB3010081, KB3099229 and KB3133719.

You have attempted to install the Media Feature Pack for 1508, 1511, and 1607.  The three patches you attempted to install are not applicable to your 1703 installation of Windows 10.

> Windows 10    1508    10240   https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3010081
>
> Windows 10    1511    10586   https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3099229
>
> Windows 10    1607    14393   https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3133719

You should download the Media Feature Pack designed to be installed on your 1703 instead.

> It still will not recognize my Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+ running Android
>   7.0

It will not recognize your Android device because you still have not installed the Media Feature Pack for `Windows 10 Version 1703`.  You must use the Media Feature Pack for the version of Windows you have installed otherwise the Windows Feature Pack will not actually be installed.

> Windows 10    1703    15063   https://support.microsoft.com/kb/4016817

Here is a link to it.

- [Media Feature Pack for N edition of Windows 10 Version 1703 (April 2017)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016817/media-feature-pack-for-n-edition-of-windows-10-version-1703-april-2017)

Here is a link to which lists the applicable patches for all builds of Windows 10.

- [Media Feature Pack list for Windows N editions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3145500/media-feature-pack-list-for-windows-n-editions)